# React Token Undefined (but in Postman I can have the token)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, token

I use an route app.get('/jwtid')
to catch the token on home in my react app.
This route work with postman and my sever send me the token
but when I do a get axios on React I got an undefined token on my server.

Here is my authJwt.js:

```html
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const config = require("../config/auth.config.js");


verifyToken = (req, res, next) => {
  const token = req.cookies.jwt;
  console.log(req.cookies.jwt);
  if (!token) {
    return res.status(403).send({
      message: "No token provided!"
    });
  }
  jwt.verify(token, config.secret, (err, decoded) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(401).send({  
        message: "Unauthorized!"
      });
    }
    req.id = decoded.id;
    next();
  });
};

const authJwt = {
  verifyToken: verifyToken,
};

module.exports = authJwt;
```

My route jwtid:

```html
app.get('/jwtid', verifyToken, (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).send(res.locals.id)
});
```

My React get token app.js React:

```html
import "./App.css";
import React from "react";
import Route from './components/Route';
import axios from "axios";
import { token } from "morgan";
import { EmailJSResponseStatus } from "@emailjs/browser";

function App() {

  let user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"));
console.log(user);
console.log("tokenId")

  const config ={
    token: user
  };
  console.log(config)
  console.log("config")

  axios({
    'method': "get",
    'url': `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}jwtid`, config,
    'withCredentials': true,
    'body': JSON.stringify(config),
  })  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response.data);
    // I need this data here ^^
    return response.data;
})
  .then((res) => {
    if (res.error) { 
      console.log(res.error);
      alert("The response data is invalid")
    } })
  .catch((err) => console.log("No token"))

  return (
    <div> 
      <Route/>
    </div> 
  );
}

export default App;
```

And I catch token withe localstorage so I call it on my axios get token, this is my return:

[console result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRDDD.png)

If someone have an solution :')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:
In my front "login.js" when I call "axios" for post my login,
I must add withCredentials: true.
Like this:

```html
axios({
            method: "post",
            url: `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}api/auth/login`, 
            data: values,
            withCredentials: true,
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json'
               },
              body: JSON.stringify(values),
          })
```

Thank to this post: [cookie httponly not sent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63156982/cookie-httponly-not-sent)

Answer (score 0):

In React, you send the token in body `'body': JSON.stringify(config)` and in Node.js you set received on cookies `const token = req.cookies.jwt;`

So you need to change the token variable into `const token = req.body.token`